# "last time index was used" showing many columns. "not used indexes" showing one column, with 0 reads

Tags: sql-server-2014

So I got this query to check unused indexes:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id) AS 'Table Name',
        i.name AS 'Index Name',
        i.index_id,
        user_updates AS 'Total Writes',
        user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups AS 'Total Reads',
        user_updates - ( user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups ) AS 'Difference'
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON s.object_id = i.object_id
                                                       AND i.index_id = s.index_id
WHERE   OBJECTPROPERTY(s.object_id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
        AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
        AND user_updates > ( user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups )
        AND i.index_id > 1
ORDER BY 'Difference' DESC,
         'Total Writes' DESC,
         'Total Reads' ASC,1,2
```

That gives me this:

[image]

Row Number 2 has `TABLE1` `INDEX_1` ( fake names obviously ). And as it's seen, Total Reads is 0.

I have another query, to check last time the index was used:

```
SELECT    [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(t1.object_id)
,t2.index_id, t2.name as index_name,t1.last_user_update, t1.last_user_seek, t1.last_user_scan, t1.last_user_lookup

FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats t1
join sys.indexes t2
    on t1.object_id=t2.object_i
    ORDER BY 1
```

I filtered to only check for `INDEX_1` and I have this:

[image]

Many rows, with the same index for `Table_1` and `Index_1`

and I would like to understand this:

1)Why in the first query I have 0 reads if in the second one we can clearly see many seeks, scans, etc etc?

2. Why there's many rows for only one index? Index_ID is the same in all rows, tablename and index name, so for sure it's just 1 index.

EDIT:

I believe the second query is wrong since directly from the DMV theres only 1 row ( highlighted rows are the ones I need. )

[image]

Comment: Rather that haphazardly reinventing all these wheels, why not use [sp_BlitzIndex](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/main/sp_BlitzIndex.sql) and see what it gives you for results? If you're worried about learning the DMVs yourself or you can't use 3rd party scripts... all the queries you need are in there and open source.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm totally off my mark, I believe you need to add index_id to your join on the second query

```
SELECT
    [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(t1.object_id),
    t2.index_id,
    t2.name as index_name,
    t1.last_user_update,
    t1.last_user_seek,
    t1.last_user_scan,
    t1.last_user_lookup,
    t1.user_updates
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats t1
JOIN sys.indexes t2
    ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id
    AND t1.index_id = t2.index_id
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: yeah, i think the second query is wrong. even with your join it didnt work as expected, but see the update in the question, I could at least see one row directly from the dmv for each index and table. will work on that thanks bro. will see if someone has a better suggestion and I go with your answer

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that the stats in the DMV are reset?

> The counters are initialized to empty whenever the database engine is
> started. Use the sqlserver_start_time column in sys.dm_os_sys_info to
> find the last database engine startup time. In addition, whenever a
> database is detached or is shut down (for example, because AUTO_CLOSE
> is set to ON), all rows associated with the database are removed.
>
> When an index is used, a row is added to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
> if a row does not already exist for the index. When the row is added,
> its counters are initially set to zero.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Perhaps it is better readable when you combine the results in 1 query?:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id) AS 'Table Name',
        i.name AS 'Index Name',
        i.index_id,
        user_updates AS 'Total Writes',
        user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups AS 'Total Reads',
        user_updates - ( user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups ) AS 'Difference',
        s.last_user_update,
        s.last_user_seek,
        s.last_user_scan,
        s.last_user_lookup,
        s.user_updates
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON s.object_id = i.object_id
                                                       AND i.index_id = s.index_id
WHERE   OBJECTPROPERTY(s.object_id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
        AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
        AND user_updates > ( user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups )
        AND i.index_id > 1
ORDER BY 'Difference' DESC,
         'Total Writes' DESC,
         'Total Reads' ASC,1,2
```